# Undoing a RenderTransform programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a Behavior that adds a `TranslateTransform` to a `ContentPresenter`'s `RenderTransform`, and adjusts it's `.Y` offset value. At some point I want to remove that `TranslateTransform` and return the `ContentPresenter` to it's original location.

How do I remove the transform and return the `ContentPresenter` to it's original location?

This is how the transform is added and adjusted...

```
       if (presenter.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform == null)
            presenter.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        ((TranslateTransform)presenter.RenderTransform).Y -= offset;
```

Some things I have tried to remove the transform...

```
// does not work...
presenter.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();

// does not work either...
presenter.RenderTransform = null;
```

[Here](https://github.com/RSchwoerer/code-examples/tree/master/ListBoxAnimatedGroup) is the complete demo project, I made a few small changes from the original from [here](http://www.japf.fr/2010/11/a-wpf-behavior-to-improve-grouping-in-your-listbox/comment-page-1/).

In the demo below, you can see if you scroll slowly it puts the ContentControl in the correct place. However if you scroll with the mousewheel quickly it does not.
The code is supposed to be removing the `RenderTransform` from the previously floated `ContentControl`.

[image]

Comment: Both *should* work, as well as setting Y to zero. Otherwise there is something you haven't shown here.

Comment: @Clemens: thanks, I added the demo project and a more specific description of the problem. I was trying to keep it generic originally.